# How to check if authentication works in twisted?

Tags: python, ssl, soap, twisted

I'm using this Wombat API - WAPI ([link](http://www.wombat-project.eu/2011/04/the-wombat-api-wapi-is-now-ava.html)) which is built on top of twisted and SOAP to enable encrypted client-server communication, mainly for sharing big datasets.

The WAPI is pretty easy to install and start using because it includes example client and server code (files: wapi_client.py and wapi_server.py).

I manage to create a simple dataset 'mydataset' and the needed SSL certificates using my CA from openssl:

- ca_cert.pem,
- server_cert.pem,
- client_cert.pem.

Using the first 2 certificates, I run the wapi_server (on 127.0.0.1:8080) without problem and get the following output:

```
> python wapi_server.py 
> setting up WAPI server!
> adding dataset mydataset
> launching dataset-specific initialization code
> registered object simulation (2 methods,0 refs)
> registered object dataset (0 methods,1 refs)
> dataset successfully initialized
> activating SSL support
> activating SSL support
> enabling SSL client authentication
> entering in twisted loop!
```

Then using certificates 1 and 3 I run the wapi_client (on the same machine using 127.0.0.1:8080) but I get the following error:

```
> python wapi_client.py
> registering dataset mydataset -> http://127.0.0.1:8080/
> entering into main thread loop
> running reactor..
> testing dataset availability
> SOAP call get_attributes
> blocking and waiting for object completion
> something went wrong: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.]
> object completed
> mydataset : ERROR
> 0 datasets are available
> getting out of main loop
```

I do not understand the error. I think it is because one of the following:

- the server is not responding
- the authentication fails (I have some mistake in using the certificates)

How do I check if my authentication works and how do I check if the server responds?

Comment: This isn't really a question about Twisted, but a question about WOMBAT pretty specifically.  I started looking into how to answer this for you, but without a ton more information (a script that sets things up the way you have them, for example) I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Glyph thank you very much! Anyway, I found the solution for my problem, I just forgot to post it here. There's a configuration file for the client in which the destination address should be of type: https://<ip_address>:<port>/<name_of_dataset>. This solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for using Twisted, and thanks for following up with your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whoever uses the Wombat package and runs to this problem, the solution is as follows:

The WAPI client is configured in file `wapi.conf`. In it you should specify the address to the server like:

```
https://<ip_address>:<port>/<name_of_dataset>
```

Note the https (secure) and the name of the dataset in the url. Furthermore, in the config file you should provide the certificate files (both CA and server certificate)